# Tell, whether we are in debug mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, environment

How to do it ? Maybe there is some environment var ?

Comment: Do you mean "development" mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three environments by default: development, test and production. 
In rails 3 you can check it using:

```
Rails.env
```

In rails 2 you can check it using:

```
RAILS_ENV
```

http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/env/class